# как конвентировать Image в Bitmap?

Tags: java, android

Я работаю с камерой и она возвращает `Image` который я хочу передать в другое активити для preview, чтоб юзер мог посмотреть на сделанное фото. Передаю я этот `Image` с помощью `intent`, но он не хочет принимать `Image` и в самом `intent` подчеркивает его красным и пишет `Cannot resolve method`

```
Image image = (Image) msg.obj;
intent.putExtra("Image", image);
```

Я так понимаю, что он принимает `Bitmap` и тут у меня вопрос... Как конвентировать Image To Bitmap? Допустим я могу конвентировать `Image` в `byte[]`

**Вот так**

```
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
```

но все равно как тогда `byte[]` конвентировать в Bitmap?

**У меня есть функция которая конвентирует `Bitmap` в `byte[]`**

```
private byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() *
            bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

но как ее заставить сделать обратное?

Подскажите как это правильно сделать?

Comment: msg это объект от Message?. Если да, то он расширен Parcelable и подходит для передачи в интент. После принимай и сужай не до Image а до Bitmap, возможно нет необходимости в потоках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
byte[] data = ...;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно точно это сделать следующим способом

1. Создать bitamp через new
2. установить размеры через setHeight и setWidth
3. пройтись двойным циклом примерно так

   ```
   for (int x=0;x < Width;i++)
           for (int y=0; y < Height; y++)
              setPixel(x,y , get_color(x,y) );
   ```

   get_color(x,y) - получение цвета исходного изображения из массива.

посмотрите так же методы

```
setPixels(int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

и `copyPixelsFromBuffer(Buffer src)`